# Python PyQt6 Problems with memory

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt6

I'm creating automation for website using Selenium and PyQt6 for GUI.
I have two processes in QThread (Authorization on website and Sending messages to users on website)

Everything is working but after a few hours my programm is crashing on MacOs or Windows.
In reason of crashing I always see "Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 10 Bus error: 10 "

How can I find out how to solve this trouble?

I'm trying to find out how to solve this trouble. I have some thoughts that I'm working bad with memory using PyQt6 or with QThreads

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.